# Eshell-print only works when called from eshell

Tags: elisp, eshell

The function eshell-print has some weird behavior, as it only seems to work when called as a part of an eshell process. All other times it throws the error

> wrong type arguments: arrayp, nil

Try to execute this function inside the scratch buffer:

```
(defun test ()
  (eshell)
  (eshell-print "Hello world"))

(test)
```

This doesn't run, even without an init file. If you try this, however, it works:

```
(progn
   (eshell)
   (eshell-return-to-prompt)
   (insert "test")
   (eshell-send-input))
```

Does anyone know why it exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the eshell code, I think that particular error is a bug.

That said, *eshell-print*, needs is a place to send its output, and *eshell-commands* is what gives a location to send output.

So change the code to:

```
(defun test ()
  (eshell)
  (eshell-commands (eshell-print "Hello world")))

(test)
```

And this will print "Hello world" inside the eshell buffer.